# enable/ disable checkbox in a gridview using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, aspxgridview

I have a gridview with 3 checkboxes and button. I want to write the conditions below in jquery:

if the checkbox 1 ist checked, the checkbox 2 shall automatically be disabled and checkbox 3 shall automatically be checked

if the checkbox 2 ist checked, the checkbox 1 shall automatically be disabled and checkbox 3 shall automatically be checked

if none of the checkbox 1 and the checkbox 2 shall ist checked, they shall automatically be enabled and checkbox 3 shall automatically be unchecked

checkbox 3 shall automatically be checked only if one of the checkbox 1 and the checkbox 2 ist checked

the checkbox 1 and the checkbox 2 don't have to be checked at the same time.

if all the checkboxes 3 of the gridview are checked, the status of the button the shall be changed to ready.

Thanks

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="True" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function selectedChk(chkbox) {

       var chk1 = document.getElementById(chkbox);
       var chk2 = document.getElementById(chkbox);
       var chk3 = document.getElementById(chkbox);


        if (chk1.checked == true)
        {
            chk2.disabled = true
            chk2.checked == false
            chk3.checked == true
        }
        else if (chk2.checked == true)
        {
            chk1.disabled = true
            chk1.checked == false
            chk3.checked == true
        }
        else{


            chk3.checked == false

        }

    }

</script> 

  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="myPanel" runat="server">

        <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gwd" runat="server" CellPadding="1" CssClass="gwd" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >


                    <Columns>

                        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="chk1">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                chk1
                                <br />

                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server"  onclick="selectedChk(this)" Checked='<%# Bind("chk1") %>'   />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>


                            <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="chk2">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                chk2
                                <br />

                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk2" runat="server"  onclick="selectedChk(this)" Checked='<%# Bind("chk2") %>'   />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>



                           <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="chk3">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                chk3
                                <br />

                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk3" runat="server" onclick="selectedChk(this)" Checked='<%# Bind("chk3") %>'   />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="not ready" 
                                    Text="not ready"  DataBinding="OnDataBinding" />

                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>


                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="id">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="id" Width="0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>



                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>

     </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: share what you have tried so far

Comment: I share it already.